# Wikipedia's Source of Snake Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra

I find Wikipedia's presentation of the Snake Lemma to be very nice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma).

Though the snake lemma can be found in virtually any textbook, ironically I have not found a textbook that states it in this form so neatly and concisely as Wikipedia. Can anyone point me a reference? (I wish to cite it and study it in greater detail).

Sources I have looked through:
- Serge Lang Algebra: 
[image]

The naming of the morphism $f$ for both the map from $M'$ to $M$, and also $N'$ to $N$ is quite confusing for the beginner, though Lang did clarify it a little.

Rotman's Homological Algebra:
[image]
Rotman's diagram has 2 extra zeroes on the top left and bottom right. I am not an expert, but I think this forces some of the maps to be injective/surjective and hence is not the most general case.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is stated as such in Hilton & Stammbach (which is an awesome reference in general):

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! I was checking out this book as well but missed it as it wasn’t listed in the index

Comment: @yoyostein Yes, interestingly they chose to leave the snake lemma anonymous!

Answer (score 2):

Here is Bourbaki's version of the Snake lemma (*Commutative Algebra*, Ch. 1 *Flat Modules*, § 1 n°4, prop. 2:

[image]